# How to upload my app (Android apk file) which is over 50MB on Google Play store?

Tags: android, google-play

My app apk file's volume is 56MB, so can't upload on Google Play store because it is over 50MB limit.

My app's image resource has occupied following:
(drawable-hdpi, 319 files, 12.5MB
 drawable-mdpi, 346 files, 12.7MB
 drawable-xhdpi, 126 files, 11.9MB
 drawable-xxxhdpi, 9 files, 11.2MB)
total 48.3MB

Should I separate resource files to expansion file?
Is there another solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try to optimize your png size if you have not done so.

Here is a free and common tools

https://pngquant.org/

Comment: My app size is reduced from 56.3MB to 26.8MB :D

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Reduce your bitmaps size (reduce quality or pixel size), that is the best way because you can't upload apk over 50Mb. The "only way" to do it, is by having an installer app (apk) and download the extra files to sdcard (like obb files). Read the oficial documentation: http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Answer (score 1):

Although @Derek has already suggested one good solution. Here is one more suggestion.

As per Google's information, currently only 14.3% of devices are having `mdpi` density. I think you can remove files from the `drawable-mdpi` which are targeting `mdpi` screen density. Just in case if your app will be installed on mdpi screen density device Android framework will pick drawables from hdpi so there will not be any issue.
Google link- https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Screens

Comment: I used the mdpi resolution for galaxy tab 10.1.  so.. can't remove this resolution image..  Thanks VicJordan for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

**As of recently** (Sept. 2015)**, you are able to upload APKs up to 100 MB** if you are targeting Android 2.3 and above - you can read more about it [on this help page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2481797?hl=en-GB). Since your app is 56 MB, you should be okay. There is also the Android developers blogspot article explaining the changes [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/support-for-100mb-apks-on-google-play.html).

Alternatively, or if your app exceeds the 100 MB APK limit, you can use **expansion files**. These are additional files that are downloaded after your app has installed and can be up to 4 GB (to be specific, you can have two expansion files of up to 2 GB each). You can learn more about expansion files on [this page on the Android Developers website](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html).